# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I heve two Mysql tables

participants

```
id   |   name   | lastname |
----------------------------
1    |    Jon   |   Bush   |
2    |  Stephen |   Eagle  |
```

and

posts

```
id    |  parentid |  Title  |   text
--------------------------------------
1     |    1      |  Title1 |  Text1
2     |   1       | title3  |  text2
3     |      1    | title4  | text4
4     |      2    |   title |   ttext
```

And I need get out table

```
id (1) | Jon   | <a href='index.php?id='1'>Title1</a>, <a href='index.php?id='2'>title3</a>, <a href='index.php?id='3'>title4</a>
id (2) | Stephen | <a href='index.php?id='4'>title<a/>
```

So i need get out Title with hyperlink with contain ID.

I use

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.Title) TitleList
FROM    participants a
        INNER JOIN posts b
            ON a.ID = b.parentID
GROUP   BY  a.ID, a.Name
```

but in this case i can get out only  Title row without ID row...

Regards

Comment: So you are attempting to retrieve the hyperlinks directly from the query? It can be done but it would be better to place that into your presentation logic in the PHP code.

Comment: No it can be php side script. But how i can get Id row as a variable?

Comment: I'd forego the `GROUP_CONCAT()` entirely, and just select the columns you need.  Construct the links in your output loop after fetching. You would just need a variable to test when `a.ID` changes in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(b.Title) TitleList
```

should instead be:

```
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("<a href='index.php?id=", b.id, "'", b.Title, "</a>") ) TitleList
```

---

Notice that it'll give you

```
<a href='index.php?id=1'>Title1</a>
```

which is correct way of hyper-linking.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  a.id, 
  a.name,  
  group_concat(b.id) ids, 
  group_concat(b.title) titles,
  group_concat(concat("<a href='index.php?id=", b.id, "'>", b.title, "</a>")) titlelist
from participants a
inner join
  posts b on b.parentid = a.id
group by a.id,a.name
```

[sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e0f2/7)

I would suggest you assign the link into your PHP code.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this will do

`SELECT  a.ID, a.Name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(concat(b.Title,'-',b.id)) TitleList
FROM    participants a
        INNER JOIN posts b
            ON a.ID = b.parentID
GROUP   BY  a.ID, a.Name`